# SQL MAX COUNT SOLUTION

Tags: sql, count, max

I have a Table named "preventivi" , in this table i have column "ImportoTOT" and "CodCliente". In this table the record is multiple for client , es:

```
Cod : 1 ImportoTot 100
Cod : 2 ImportoTot 50
Cod : 1 ImportTTot 150.
```

i need to find the value max , and i need to count this record and them sum the record.

This Query is Ok for the Max, my result is :

```
Cod: 1 ImportoTot 150
Cod: 2 ImportoTot 50
```

But i Need to count the record (2 Record Count )  e Sum ( Total 200 )

```
SELECT YEAR(P.DataPrev) Anno, MONTH(P.DataPrev) Mese, DATENAME(MONTH, P.DataPrev) Descrizione_Mese, Max(P.ImportoTot) NumPrevEmessi
,p.cod_paz
        FROM TestPrev P 
        WHERE   
                  year(P.DataPrev) = 2020 and     MONTH(P.DataPrev) >= 09 and    day(P.DataPrev) >= 01
          and     year(P.DataPrev) = 2020 and     MONTH(P.DataPrev) <= 09 and    day(P.DataPrev) <= 30
```

Thanks !

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytical function as follows:

```
select count(*) as num_record_distinct, sum(NumPrevEmessi) as sm from
(SELECT YEAR(P.DataPrev) Anno, 
       MONTH(P.DataPrev) Mese, 
       DATENAME(MONTH, P.DataPrev) Descrizione_Mese, 
       P.ImportoTot as NumPrevEmessi ,
       p.cod_paz,
       row_number() over (partition by p.cod_paz order by P.ImportoTot desc) as rn
  FROM TestPrev P 
 WHERE year(P.DataPrev) = 2020 
   and .....) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> i need to find the value max , and i need to count this record and them sum the record.

Isn't this just aggregation?

```
SELECT YEAR(P.DataPrev) as Anno, MONTH(P.DataPrev) as Mese, 
       DATENAME(MONTH, P.DataPrev) as Descrizione_Mese, 
       Max(P.ImportoTot) as NumPrevEmessi,
       COUNT(*),
       SUM(P.ImportoTot)
FROM TestPrev P 
WHERE P.DataPrev >= '2020-09-01' AND
      P.DataPrev < '2020-10-01'
GROUP BY YEAR(P.DataPrev), MONTH(P.DataPrev), DATENAME(MONTH, P.DataPrev);
```

It is unclear if you want the code as well in the results.  If so, it should be in both the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT p.cod_paz, YEAR(P.DataPrev) as Anno, MONTH(P.DataPrev) as Mese, 
       DATENAME(MONTH, P.DataPrev) as Descrizione_Mese, 
       Max(P.ImportoTot) as NumPrevEmessi,
       COUNT(*),
       SUM(P.ImportoTot)
FROM TestPrev P 
WHERE P.DataPrev >= '2020-09-01' AND
      P.DataPrev < '2020-10-01'
GROUP BY p.cod_paz, YEAR(P.DataPrev), MONTH(P.DataPrev), DATENAME(MONTH, P.DataPrev);
```

Note that the date comparisons have been changed.  In addition to being more readable and simpler to type, direct date comparisons are easier for the optimizer to use and allow the use of an index on `DataPrev`.

Answer (score 0):

Not Function, the first solution is ok for 1 Month, my result is
09 - 527 - 556200

I need 01/01/2020 thru 31/12/2020

08 - 200 - 56000
09 - 527 - 556200
ecc. ecc.

I launch th query I obtain

100005  2020    5   May 25  1   25
100005  2020    6   June    87  1   87
100013  2020    2   February    64  1   64
100013  2020    7   July    64  1   64
100013  2020    11  November    64  1   64
100082  2020    6   June    274 1   274
100087  2020    1   January 41  1   41
100087  2020    6   June    41  1   41
100104  2020    7   July    5780    1   5780

and is error

thanks for all